# "Invalid Identifier" Error while trying to add a column using "alter" in Sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ddl

I was trying to add a column named 'description' to the table named 'building.

```
ALTER TABLE building ADD COLUMN description varchar(255) NOT NULL;
```

Im getting this error as :

> **SQL ERROR: ALTER TABLE building ADD COLUMN description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier**

i googled my problems, even tried gpts

Answer (score 1):

As shown [in the syntax diagrams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877__I2183462), you should not have the `COLUMN` keyword - that is being seen as the column name, and is a reserved word, so it indeed an invalid identifier.

It should just be:

```
ALTER TABLE building ADD description varchar(255) NOT NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vwV7Sygm)

As commented, consider using `varchar2` instead of `varchar` as Oracle recommends, though they're synonymous at the moment (they've been threating for them to diverge for 30+ years...)

Answer (score 0):

Needed fixes:

1. Alter TABLE Syntax.
2. Use of datatype- varchar instead of varchar2.

SQL syntax for adding a column doesn't use COLUMN keyword in the ALTER statement. Instead, directly use column_name ie, description directly.

Wrong Syntax:

`ALTER TABLE building ADD COLUMN description varchar(255) NOT NULL;`

Correct syntax:

`ALTER TABLE building ADD description varchar2(255) NOT NULL;`